# Multivariable limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{(y^2-x)^3}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to solve the limit
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{(y^2-x)^3}{x^2+y^4}$$
and I can't think on a possible upper bound for it.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Answer is 0 although I graphed it...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Take $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^4}$, so you can write $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y^2 = r \sin(\theta)$.  Then your function becomes
    $$ \dfrac{(r \sin (\theta) - r \cos(\theta))^3}{r^2 \cos^2(\theta) + r^2 \sin^2(\theta)} = r (\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta))^3$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{(y^2-x)^3}{x^2+y^4}$$

Let $$
f(x,y)=\dfrac{(y^2-x)^3}{x^2+y^4}
$$
Then $$
\lim_{(0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(0,0)} f(x^2,y)\\
|f(x^2,y)|= \dfrac{|y^2-x^2|^3}{x^4+y^4}\le
\dfrac{(y^2+x^2)^3}{x^4+y^4} \\
=  \dfrac{r^6}{r^4 (\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta)}  = O(r^2)
$$using polar coordinates. Then the limit is 0.

Comment: I would think that looking at $f(x,\sqrt{y})$ would be a little bit more natural since the trig relations pop out more cleanly.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using trig or polar coordinates? I just don't want to use them because we haven seen that yet in school, and I don't know if Im supposed to solve it with another method... Although I don't mind to use polar coordinates if I have to.

Comment: well, you can show that $\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^4+y^4}$ is bounded.

Comment: @mookid how would that help?

Comment: because $|f(x^2,y)|\le (x^2 + y^2)*(x^2+y^2)^2/(x^4+y^4) $ and $x^2 + y^2\to 0$

Comment: @mookid could you show me how you bounded it please?